# WPF: ItemsControl's border not visible

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

I followed the instruction in [this blog](http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-add-scrollintoview-to.html) to add `ScrollIntoView` to `ItemsControl`.

But this makes the border invisible:

```
<ItemsControl BorderBrush="Black"
              BorderThickness="3">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
</ItemsControl>
```

In order to display the border, I have to remove:

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
```

But this way I won't be able to use the `ScrollIntoView` method.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the border in the template.

```
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ItemsPresenter />

                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
```